# Determine nullable item from Dictionary generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "foo", 2.5 } };
```

And I have to determine the value by a generic method

```
public static Type GetRes<Type>(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key) && dict[key].GetType() == typeof(Type))
    {
        return (Type)dict[key];
    }
    return default(Type);
}
```

The call looks the following

```
double? result1 = GetRes<double?>(dict, "foo"); // expected 2.5
double? result2 = GetRes<double?>(dict, "bar"); // expected null
```

unfortunately this doesn't work at `dict[key].GetType() == typeof(Type)` the result is always false because `typeof(double) == typeof(double?)` is always false.

---

**What I've tried:**

```
// changed the call from double? to double
double? result1 = GetRes<double>(dict, "foo"); 
double? result2 = GetRes<double>(dict, "bar");
```

Methdod:

```
// chagned Type to Nullable<Type>
public static Nullable<Type> GetRes<Type>(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key) && dict[key].GetType() == typeof(Type))
    {
        return (Nullable<Type>)dict[key];
    }
    return default(Nullable<Type>);
}
```

This doesn't compile.

Comment: `((object)(int?)5).GetType() == typeof(int)`, while `((object)(int?)null) == null`. Boxing of nullable value types works in this way. You can't do anything. If the value type is `null` then the boxed reference is `null`, if it isn't `null` then the value of the nullable type is boxed. There is no possible full `Nullable<T>` boxed value. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/boxing-nullable-types

Comment: Can you try with dict[key] is Type

Comment: Why do you need the extra `dict[key].GetType() == typeof(Type)` check? If your dictionary does contain the requested key, go ahead and try to cast it to the desired type, otherwise it returns `default(T)`

Comment: @haim770 `default(T)` in case of `double` is `0` so I don't know if the result is `0` or the values wasn't found

Comment: Just remove `dict[key].GetType() == typeof(Type)` check and leave everything else the same. There is no need for it. If there is a value for given key but it's of wrong type - your program has a bug which you need to fix and not hide it under the carpet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add `where Type : struct` as follow:

```
public static Type? GetRes2<Type>(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key) where Type : struct
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(key) && dict[key].GetType() == typeof(Type))
    {
        return (Type?)dict[key];
    }
    return default(Type?);
}
```

The type 'Type' must be a `non-nullable value type` in order to use it as parameter 'T'. Then you can force 'Type' to be `value type` by using `where Type : struct`.

Comment: `return default(Type?);` will always be `return null;`

Comment: Yes. default of Nullable<Type> is always null!

Answer (score 0):

Why not check dict[key] is your Type:

```
 public static Type GetRes<Type>(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(key) && dict[key] is Type)
            {
                return (Type)dict[key];
            }
            return default(Type);
        }
```

Comment: `default(double)` returns `0` and I don't know if the key doesn't exist or the result is `0`

Comment: In that case include a condition:

if (!dict.ContainsKey(key) )
            {
                return null;
            }

Answer (score 0):

The following extension method should do the trick:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
    }

    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return default(T); //Or null, depending on you needs
    }

    var value = dictionary[key];

    if (value == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    if (value is IConvertible)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }

    return (T)value;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    { "foo1", 2.5 },
    { "foo2", "my string" },
    { "foo3", new MyClass() },
    { "foo4", 1 },
    { "foo5", null }
};

var res1 = dict.GetValue<float>("foo1");
var res2 = dict.GetValue<string>("foo2");
var res3 = dict.GetValue<MyClass>("foo3");
var res4 = dict.GetValue<int>("foo4");
var res5 = dict.GetValue<int?>("foo5");
```

Try this method signature for the struct only types:

```
public static T? GetValue<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key) where T : struct
{
    //implementation should be the same
}
```

Comment: `default(double)` returns `0` and I don't know if the key doesn't exist or the result is `0`

Comment: If the key does not exist, the line "var value = dictionary[key];" will throw an exception.

Comment: The requirement is to return `null` if the value doesn't exist

Comment: See my updated answer. I´ve added a check to see if the key exists. You can also use dictionary.TryGetValue.

Comment: if type `T` is `double` you can't return null

Comment: Well, in .NET doubles are structures and not reference types... That´s why you can't make them null... But that's also why they introduced Nullable<double> or double?....

Comment: See my updated answer. That should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "is" to check for object may be casted

```
public static Type GetRes<Type>(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string key)
{
   if (dict.ContainsKey(key) && dict[key] is Type)
   {
      return (dict[key] as Type);
   }
   return default(Type);
}
```

Comment: `default(double)` returns `0` and I don't know if the key doesn't exist or the result is `0`